# How to remove binary file reference information from wasm-pack build

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

[image]

When I edit wasm with text, there is a lot of unwanted information.

Such as unnecessary ".cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823"

I am trying to add

```
[profile.release]
lto = true
opt-level = "z"
```

But the information still exists

Comment: Have you tried `wasm-opt` from [this project](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen)? it would also be helpful if you tell us how exactly you built your wasm file. "wasm-pack build" is in the title, but we don't know a lot of other information. Would be useful if you'd add them to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I tried: wasm-opt -Oz -o output.wasm input.wasm, but the problem still exists

Comment: This is my build method: wasm-pack build --release